# Website won't work after ssl installation

Tags: ssl, nginx

My website was working properly before I installed the ssl certificate. However, once it was installed, my website stopped working. Nginx starts fine as usual, and I get no errors, but the website just doesn't work. Here's my code for nginx config:

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name www.example.com; (example is replaced with my domain name in code)
location / {
      rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
  }
}
server {

listen 443 ssl;
server_name www.example.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com/ssl-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com/example.key;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {

   proxy_pass http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8004;

   proxy_http_version 1.1;

   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

   proxy_set_header Host $host;

   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

}

}
```

Comment: I actually found out that the problem was with my amazon ec2 instance security group. Mske sure to add HTTPS as one of the groups.